# how to configure jenkins `http://{jenkins_host}/configure` page with program?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i try to use python to configire system locale to adapt different language, but it failed ... i have checked the api, also get now usefull infomation, anyone can help me ?

In [15]: import requests

In [16]: url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/configSubmit"

In [17]: headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

In [18]: resp = requests.post(url, data={'systemLocale': 'en_US'}, headers=headers)

In [19]: resp.ok
Out[19]: False

In [20]: resp.text
Out[20]: u'\n\n\nError 403 No valid crumb was included in the request\n\n

### HTTP ERROR 403

\n

Problem accessing /configSubmit. Reason:\n

```
    No valid crumb was included in the request
```

---

*Powered by Jetty://*

---

\n\n\n\n'

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error, change to Jenkins user by using the following command

```
su – Jenkins –s /bin/bash
```

then go to the config.xml and do the respective changes as shown below

```
vi /var/lib/Jenkins/config.xml
```

[image]